# how the list elements will be stored in java

Tags: java, hibernate, list, postgresql

Below is my code (postgresql,java,hibernate)

```
String squery="select starttime,reachtime from train where loc='hyderabad' ";
list=session.createSQLQuery(squery).list();
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{
    System.out.println("list has"+list.get(i));
}
```

how the list elements starttime,reachtime will be stored.At which positions?Please help me

Comment: how are you populating the list?

Comment: Can you please the relevant code how you retrieve the data and store it in the `List`?

Answer (score 1):

`I tried with list.get(i) for displaying but getting some unexpected symbols like @345J234.`

This is because you are printing the object itself and this is the default `toString()` method. If you override the toString() you can get whatever you need as message when calling the object directly. What I think you want to achieve is `list.get(i).getName()` where `getName()` is a method in your class

Comment: How can I iterate through the list to get starttime and reachtime seperately.Can u please help me..

Comment: I cannot give you a straight answer as I am not aware of your SQL API.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using @Entity, @Table annotations for you DAO class? If yes then proceed.

Assuming that your **'Train'** table is mapped to a POJO class called **Train** using **@Table(name="TRAIN")** annotation and assuming that you have the relevant columns mapped using **@Column**, you can do the following:

```
Iterator trainIter=sess.createQuery("<your query>").iterate();
while ( trainIter.hasNext() ) {
    Train currentTrain = (Train) iter.next();  // fetch the object
    System.out.println("Train name is :"+currentTrain.getName());
    System.out.println("Train start time is :"+currentTrain.getStartTime());
    System.out.println("Train stop time is :"+currentTrain.getStopTime());
}
```

Comment: thank you.It is help ful..And I want to iterate through the list to get the starttime and reachtime seperately and of all the records.How can I achieve.please help me.

Comment: I replied before you edited your code and before I could see that you are using hibernate. Hence the overhaul of my answer.